# Error linking with clang+llvm

Tags: optimization, llvm, clang

I am trying to apply LLVM optimizations to a few Image Feature Extraction algorithms which have been implemented using openCV. The LLVM-based profiler works fine with simple programs (For instance, HelloWorld), and the feature extraction algorithms too work separately as expected.
However I was unable to use the profiler for the algorithms and got the following error while linking the OpenCV libraries to the optimized code.

```
gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-g' '-L/home/silky/opencv/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib' '-  L/home/silky/opencv/OpenCVInstall/x86/lib' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' as --gdwarf2 --64 -o /tmp/ccAhPffW.o out.s
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-g' '-L/home/silky/opencv/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib' '-L/home/silky/opencv/OpenCVInstall/x86/lib' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/collect2 --sysroot=/ --build-id --no-add-needed --as-needed --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -z relro /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/crtbegin.o -L/home/silky/opencv/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib -L/home/silky/opencv/OpenCVInstall/x86/lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../.. /tmp/ccAhPffW.o -lpthread -lrt -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_video -lopencv_nonfree -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
/tmp/ccAhPffW.o:(.debug_info+0x49a14): undefined reference to `.Lline_table_start1'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've used the following commands to compile and link the files.

```
clang -emit-llvm -c -Wall -g  -O0  -DCLOCK_GETTIME_TIMING -DOPENCV_2_4  -I/home/opencv/OpenCVInstall/x86/include -o ThreadManager.bc FeatureExtraction/ThreadManager.cpp
clang -emit-llvm -c -Wall -g  -O0  -DCLOCK_GETTIME_TIMING -DOPENCV_2_4 -I/home/opencv/OpenCVInstall/x86/include -o FeatureExtraction.bc FeatureExtraction/FeatureExtraction.cpp

llvm-link  FeatureExtraction.bc ThreadManager.bc -o FE.bc
clang $CFLAGS -o profiler.o cacheSim.cpp //LLVM profiler
opt -load /home/llvm/llvm/Debug+Asserts/lib/cacheProf.so -cacheProf FE.bc>out.bc

llc FE.bc -o out.s
g++ -v -g  out.s  profiler.o -L/home/opencv/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib -L/home/opencv/OpenCVInstall/x86/lib  -lpthread -lrt -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_video -lopencv_nonfree
```

Could some one please tell me if I am linking the files or loading the files in a wrong way?
Is clang compilation different from how g++ works?

Comment: Why are you linking with g++ when you compiled with clang?

Comment: Hi Jan,
Thank you so much for your input. The compilation works when I link with Clang. Could you please tell me how it is different from using llc to convert the .bc file to the native binary and then using g++ for linking. 
I've used g++ before for linking the profiler and source (without any external libraries) and it used to work.  Now I think I'll have to convert profiler code to .bc and use 'clang -v FE.bc profiler.bc  -L/home..... '. 
Thanks.

Comment: Usually the problem is different default options and libraries between the compilers. Which is why you should always use the same driver for compilation and linking and even pass the compiler options to linker too. But I suspect the problem in this case is in the generated `out.s`, because `.L...` is a _local_ label, unrelated to libraries. By the way I would expect clang to be able to link a `.bc` and an `.o` together; it shouldn't be necessary to convert the profiler to a `.bc`.